# What is this tool called? Variable frequency drive + function generator=?

Tags: high-frequency, tools

For a while (probably since I found out that switch mode power supply transformers run at different frequenciess, much higher than mains) I've wanted a device that can produce different frequencies, voltages (0-50) and wave forms so I could test high frequency transformers if I wanted to.

I know function generators exist but those seem like they put out a waveform that while precise, the unit as a whole is underpowered and under voltage for the ideas I have. Variable frequency drives exist but they won't reach the frequencies I desire and I'm pretty sure they aren't bench equipment.

Is there something I'm missing? What would a device that gives you control of the voltage, frequency and waveform but large power output be called? How can I buy/make one or does this device not exist and there some law of physics that would make such a device impractical?

Comment: How much power do you need? I asked [something similar](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/379130/high-power-but-low-frequency-arbitrary-waveform-generator) here a while ago. Your best bet seems to be power audio amplifiers (e.g. for PA systems)

Comment: You connect a power amplifier (purchased or built) up to a function generator. Be prepared to spend.